# How to waits the thread till another thread completes

Tags: android, multithreading, gridview

I want to show the progress dialog while loading the images in grid view.
The problem i'm facing was the current thread and Progress Dialog thread running simultaniously.

```
 public String Method1(){
        String output="";
        final ProgressDialog aProgDialogL = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...");
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run () {
                //My codes
                aHandlerL.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Post Runnable codes
                        aProgDialogL.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        thread.start();

        /*
         * 
         * 
         * OTHER CODES
         * 
         * 
         */
        return output;
 }
```

In the above example I need to run the code inside Progress Dialog Thread. After it finish executing i need to run my "OTHER CODES". How to do it?
.
I tried using Async task. Before async task completes method1 gets extcuted and reurning the string.

```
    public String Method1(){
    String result="";
    new GetImages().execute();
    return result;

}
public class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        aProgDialogL = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "", "Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Progress Dialig Code
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        aProgDialogL.dismiss();
        //OTHER CODES
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is happening in "OTHER CODES"? UI manipulation or something else?

Comment: I should not return the object till progress dialog thread completes. UI Manipulation also there.

Comment: do pd.show() in onPreExecute() and dismiss it in onPostexecute(). Do your long running operation such as downloading a file in doInBackGround()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Async task. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. There is a good tutorial here. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html.Also have a look at this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html. Use asynctask modify it according to your needs.

```
     doInBackground()- For long running operations. Don't update ui here.
     onPreExecute()- update ui before running the operatio nin background.
     onPostExecute()- update ui after running the operation.
```

Comment: I tried using asyc task, still i'm not able to do. my asyc task code is added in my ques. please check and tell me the changes i need to do.

Comment: There is a example and tutorial by vogella which is good. Have a look. If you google you can get working examples of asynctask.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to take somewhat different approach.

Dont involve any threads in Method1() function.Rather your Method1() function should be run under separate thread.

Below snippet will help you.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPopup))
            .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {

                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {

                        String answer = Method1();

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // Here you will write the code which is
                                // to be executed on main thread.

                            }
                        });
                    };
                }.start();
            }
        });

    }

    public String Method1() {
        // Write code

        return "result";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that : What about use Timer After specific Time Stop Your thread and and write your code you want after stop statement Like that :

```
Timer timer=new Timer();
 timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
 @Override
public void run() {
     thread.stop;
       // Other code   }
```

}, Time You want );

Comment: i need to run all the codes in side the thread. i can't predict how long the code takes to complete.